# NuGet Package Data not found on execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm using a NuGet Package with my application. While debugging and staying in the bin folder of my Project everything works fine. But as soon as I use the compiled exe outside of this folder I get an error message saying "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "CircularProgressBar, Version=2.8.0.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=310fd07b25df79b3" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden."
So that System.IO isn't able to find the Files for this package.
How can I fix this, cause it is vital to only distribute the exe

Comment: Are you moving just the EXE? If so then of course it can't find the other files because they're not there. You need to move everything that is critical from the output folder, not just the EXE. If that library is not in the output folder then it should be, so you may have to set `Copy Local` to `true` for the reference.

Comment: All the executables (including dll) in Debug or Release folder has to be in the same folder as executable when copied to another folder on same machine.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Debug or Release folder. The .dll files are included in the folder. When you move .exe file to other place, the dlls will not be found.

You can try to publish to folder and choose "produce single file". You can refer to the following steps:

1.Right-click on the project and choose Publish

[image]

2.Choose Folder and set the target location

[image]

3.Click Show all settings and change Target runtime and choose produce single file.

[image]

4.Finally publish the project you will get folder like this. And you can use the compiled exe outside of this folder

[image]